# How to make One-To-Many->One-To-Many nested select using sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize with sqlite and i want to make

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM users AS u 
    LEFT JOIN months AS m ON u.id = m.userid 
    LEFT JOIN worktimerecords AS w on m.id = w.monthid 
WHERE w.projectid = ${id}
```

..but using models, it is possible?

I've tried

```
User.findAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: Month,
            include: [
              {
                model: WorkTimeRecord,
                where: { projectId: id },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      })
```

But where doesn't work, and return users for all projects, i want return users only for one project.

Comment: try `required: true` in both `include` options

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem. 
I just add the `required: true` to `include` of `Month`.